# Simplify an algebraic sum involving $\frac{1}{x^n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to simplify the following expression:
$$
A=\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{x^3}+...+\frac{1}{x^n}
$$
I believe the answer is
$$A=\frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}}{x},$$
but I am not sure how to get to this answer.

Comment: I think you will change your mind about $$\frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}}{x}$$ after setting $x=n=1.$

Comment: Let $x=\frac 1 a$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify as follows: $$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{x^3}+...+\frac{1}{x^n}=\frac{x^{n-1}}{x^n} + \frac{x^{n-2}}{x^n}+ \frac{x^{n-3}}{x^n}+...+\frac{1}{x^n}=\frac{\overbrace{1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}}^{\text{geometric series}}}{x^n}$$

Recall the partial sum of a geometric series is $$\sum _{k=i}^{n}z^{k}={\frac {z^{i}-z^{n+1}}{1-z}}$$

You should be able to proceed.

---

Answer below.

> $$A=\frac{x^n-1}{x^n(x-1)}$$

Comment: This is a nice answer. By the way, you can use `\dots` to get better spacing around the ellipsis and have them vertically aligned with the plus signs, e.g. 
$$
1 + x + x^2 + \dots + x^{n-1} 
$$

Comment: @SammyBlack Thank you! Noted :)

Answer (score 1):

A is a geometric series, use the summation formula.